# Automatic file update on a non-svn folder while doing svn commit

Tags: svn

I have svn repository and virtual hosts set up on same linux server. Whenever the developers commit the changes, I want the site files(files at webroot) too get updated at the same time. The files at webroot is not a svn working copy. I was able to update another svn working copy using post commit hook, but dont know how to update another non-svn folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform an [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) from a post-commit hook.

Comment: I was just going to type it :)

Comment: Thanks..I tried with it..but "export" copy entire tree to the target. I need to copy only the files that updated during each commit through a hook.otherwise it wouldnt be practical for large repositories.